Телеграм бот, переводящий текст в верную раскладку
Хочу создать бота для группы своих друзей, который при ошибочном вводе предложений на русском с английской раскладки будет переводить этот набор букв в толковое предложение.
Как пример:
rfr ltkf?
Это фраза "как дела?", и мне нужно её перевести в обычный вид (на русский язык). Для этого я хочу, чтобы по написанию фразы "перевод" мой бот брал из группы последнее значение, которое было введено на английском, и переводил его соответственно.
Как это сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста. Надеюсь, всё понятно объяснил
import telebot

layout = dict(zip(map(ord, "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`" 'QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?~'), "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ё" 'ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё'))
bot = telebot.TeleBot('123')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.reply_to_message == 'перевод':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, translate(layout))
    else:
        print()

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)


сохраняете каждое сообщение в какую-нибудь переменную и когда нужно читаете его оттуда

Не обязательно брать последнее значение. Вы можете сделать бота, который будет "переводить" то сообщение на которое вы ответите (reply).
Способ получения текста нужного вам зависит от библиотеки, что вы используете, но, например для aiogram будет выглядеть примерно так:
message.reply_to_message.text

После чего вам нужно сопоставить символы в тексте с корректными, и отправить ответное сообщение.
Вам помогут с кодом, если вы покажете пример собственной реализации.
UPD После добавления автором кода:
В изначальной версии вопроса не была указана библиотека. За корректность моих названий функций библиотеки Telebot не ручаюсь.
В первую очередь, вам нужно сравнить текст сообщение с вашим ключом "перевод", соответственно message.text.lower() == "перевод". После вам нужно получить текст сообщения, на которое "перевод" является ответным будет что-то в духе txt = message.reply_to_message.text и уже у полученного текста вызывать метод строки translate.
Кроме того не рекомендую использовать print() для пропуска, есть pass для таких ситуаций (и вообще блок else не обязателен)

спасибо огромное, сейчас попробую

@Dezmoner, я не могу прикрепить скрин со своим кодом, как это сделать? Просто впервые зашел на этот ресурс и еще не совсем разобрался со всем функционалом

Вам и не надо прикреплять скриншот. Достаточно дополнить текстом в вопросе
@user624102

if message.reply_to_message == 'перевод':
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, translate(layout))

layout = dict(zip(map(ord, "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`"
'QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?~'),
"йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ё"
'ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё'))

@user624102 так, я вижу что вы хотите сделать, добавьте, пожалуйста код в текст ВОПРОСА :) (кнопка "править")

вроде вставил новый код, посмотрите пожалуйта

а как посмотреть ваш код

@user624102 вы добавили свой код к моему ответу, а не вашему ВОПРОСУ. У вас под вопросом(он выше) есть кнопка "править", нажмите туда и допишите код (или примите мою правку  с ним). В идеале, если вы добавите ошибку, которая возникает при работе (при попытке запуска кода). Так всем участникам будет виден ваш код, и они смогут давать ответы основываясь на нём.
Когда код будет добавлен непосредственно в вопрос, я отредактирую ответ, основываясь на нём.

код запускается, ошибки нету, но при этом не рабоает
